# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, file

I have a problem with my code, and i don't know how to fix it. I found many similar questions but none of them solved my problem. I'm using Visual Studio Code as a code editor. Here is my code:

```py
import discord
import json

with open('config.json') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

with open('data.json', 'r+') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as " + str(client.user))

@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.author == client.user: return

    if msg.content == '!gcsetup':
        server_json_content = {}
        server_json_content["channel"] = msg.channel.id
        webhook = await msg.channel.create_webhook(name="name")
        server_json_content["webhook"] = webhook.url
        data.append(server_json_content)
        data_file.seek(0)
        json.dump(data, data_file)

client.run(config["token"])
```

I think the error is here:

```py
    if msg.content == '!gcsetup':
        server_json_content = {}
        server_json_content["channel"] = msg.channel.id
        webhook = await msg.channel.create_webhook(name="name")
        server_json_content["webhook"] = webhook.url
        data.append(server_json_content)
        data_file.seek(0)
        json.dump(data, data_file)
```

According to the error error message:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Dev\main.py", line 26, in on_message
    data_file.seek(0)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: Where is the data_file variable defined. In other words, where did you open a file and saved it in data_file?!

Comment: @Grasshopper with open('data.json', 'r+') as data_file <- here

Comment: In your own words, what do you think `with open('data.json', 'r+') as data_file:` means? What do you think happens at the end of that block? What do you think is the *purpose* of using a `with` statement rather than simply calling `open` normally?

Comment: Besides the immediate answer to your question that other's explained, global variables are general frowned upon. They can cause bugs like this one. If you open the `data.json` file in `on_message()` using a local `with` block, then you would avoid the problem entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data_file` variable exists only in `with open('data.json', 'r+') as data_file:` block therefore you can not use it outside of `with`.
Try to write

```py
data_file = open('data.json', 'r+')
data = json.load(data_file)
```

Instead of

```py
with open('data.json', 'r+') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

Comment: then how does the config variable work?

Comment: Config variables are not declared inside a `with` block.

Answer (score 3):

When you use the [`with open()...`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase) statement to open a file handle, you implicitly close the handle at the end of the with block.  Thus, when you call `data_file.seek` you are attempting to perform an I/O operation on a closed file, as the error message indicates.

The easiest solution is just to reopen the file for writing when doing the dump.  This also obviates the need to seek to the beginning of the file, as this will be the default behavior when you open in writing mode.

```
    if msg.content == '!gcsetup':
        server_json_content = {}
        server_json_content["channel"] = msg.channel.id
        webhook = await msg.channel.create_webhook(name="name")
        server_json_content["webhook"] = webhook.url
        data.append(server_json_content)
        with open('data.json', 'w') as data_file:
            json.dump(data, data_file)
```

While you could also instead not use a with block (and thus never close the file handle), it's best practice not to keep lots of open file handles for the entirety of your discord server